# Compiler of @angular/compiler-cli?

Tags: angular, angular2-cli

What is type of compiler for @angular/compiler-cli?

> tsc compiler or ngc

Comment: I just can't believe that anyone would up vote this sorry question. I can't believe that I am commenting on it!! :)